# How to set a recurring timer in windows

Tags: windows-10, timer

I want to set a timer which auto restart after each loop.
I am trying to do so with Alarms & Clock but can't find the feature.

OS: windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not have this feature built in. There is a Feedback app you can use to find others who have suggested this, or suggest it yourself.

Absent waiting for Microsoft to maybe do this, you will need to look for alternate tools to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Task Scheduler and choose for it to run every `n` minutes.

If you would like it to alert you whenever it runs, make it run a simple batch script that makes a message appear.

If you want it to run something **AND** tell you, make a batch script to run the alert and whatever program or process you choose.